# Select tag in a many-to-many relationship doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `User` that has many `Profession`, `Occupation` is connecting the two.

I'm trying to display a select menu with the available professions, in a `@user` from bulder.

To debug I've tried the following three variations, but no code is rendered at all (the rest of the form has no problems):

```
<%= f.fields_for :occupations do |builder|  %>
  <%= builder.collection_select(:profession_id, Profession.all, :id, :title) %>
  <%= bulder.select :profession_id, Profession.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) ) %>
<% end %>

<%= select("occupation", "profession_id", Profession.all.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
```

**What could I be doing wrong here?** I get no errors, I just don't get any html for the select tag.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :professions, through: :occupations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :occupations
end

class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :occupations
end

class Occupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields_for :occupations renders nothing most likely because `@user.occupations` is empty. And you most likely mean `Profession` instead of `Person` on line 3 of your code.

To fix this you could do `@user.occupations.build` in your controller, that way your fields_for block should render html.

Comment: I did this, and now *something* is happening - don't know if it's good or bad. On reload I get the following error "undefined method `occupations_path' ". I know this is a separate question, but why does it seem to render an occupations_path?

Comment: @FellowStranger Almost certainly it's trying to create the target path for the `fields_for` and finding that there is no route helper to do so.  Use `rake routes` to figure out what's going on.  The `fields_for` target must match `PUT` and `POST` methods for the Occupation controller.

Comment: Thanks for the input, even though I'm really confused about the `fields_for` part needing a separate route - isn't the point of using `fields_for` that the associated model gets nested onto the main form object (`@user`) and inherits its' routing?

Comment: the fields_for doesn't need a route. to answer your question we would need to see your actual form code. but you want something like: ```form_for @user do |f|; f.fields_for :occupations do |of|;...;end;end```